# SQL filter query in bookshelf as Laravel in nodejs

Tags: node.js, orm, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am new to node.js and it's ORM(`bookshelf`). I need to know how to get the  user which have any particular genres.

**1).** Here `users` have multiple `genres`, means `users` hasMany genres and `genres` belongsToMany `users`.

**Ques).** How to fetch all the users which have `genres` = 1

- Below is my code trying to achive this but not able to get the correct answer.

  ```
  User.forge()
    .query(function(query){
       query.whereExists(function(){
           this.select('*').from('genres')
           .join('genres_user', function(){
              this.on('genres.id', '=', 'genres_user.genres_id');
           })
          .where('users.id', 'genres_user.user_id')
          .where('genres_id', req.query.genres);
       });
     })
    .fetchAll({
       withRelated : ['profile', 'posts']
     })
    .then(function (collection) {
       if(collection == ''){
           res.json({error: true, message:'No user found!', data:{}});
       }

       res.json({error: false, data: collection.toJson()});
    })
   .catch(function (err) {
      res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
   });
  ```

Comment: if you know Laravel, you should try https://adonisjs.com

Comment: Thanks to give time, `adonis` is a great framework but I am bound to work on `Express`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I need something like `whereHas()`(like in Laravel) in bookshelf, but there is nothing like that in `bookshelf`. But I sort it out through raw SQL queries which are as follows and working great as I required.

```
User.forge()
.query(function(query){
   query.whereExists(function(){
       this.select('*').from('genres')
       .join('genres_user', function(){
           this.on('genres.id', '=', 'genres_user.genres_id');
       })
      .whereRaw('users.id = genres_user.user_id')
      .where('genres_id', req.query.genres);
   });
})
.fetchAll({
   withRelated : ['profile', 'posts']
})
.then(function (collection) {
    if(collection == ''){
       res.json({error: true, message:'No user found!', data:{}});
    }

    res.json({error: false, data: collection.toJson()});
})
.catch(function (err) {
   res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
});
```